# The D module pushforward to a point is de Rham cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, d-modules

I have read and understood the definition of the pushforward of a $\mathcal{D}_X$-module $\mathcal{M}$ under a morphism of varieries $$f:X\longrightarrow Y$$
In particular, if $Y=\{ \star \}$ is a point and $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{O}_X$ then
$$f_* \mathcal{O}_X= \ \ \ \left( H^n(X)  \to \cdots \to H^0(X) \right)$$
is the de Rham cohomology complex of X.

However, I don't know why this *should* be true. Can anyone explain why, before reading the definition of a pushforward, one would guess this as the only possible reasonable answer?

(Maybe part of the problem is that I've not got a good picture of what this process is meant to be doing geometrically).

Comment: omg another cat! hi!

Comment: If $F$ is a sheaf on $X$ and $f : X \to \{pt\}$ then $f_*F$ is $F(X)$ and $R^iF = H^i(X,F)$. So it seems reasonable to me that you get the De Rham complex as the direct image of $\mathcal O_X$.